# How is Paneer Melting in Cheena Poda dessert?

Tags: cheese, indian-cuisine, melting, paneer

In [this (16:09)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29ZP8ADQJ1Y) Video the **Master Chef Chintan Pandya** has made a delicious dessert "Cheena Poda" in which the cheena (Paneer) seems to melt. Which is not possible because while making paneer the whey traps the minerals, Fats and is not included in the aggregated solids which is ceasin or panner. So how paneer melts in the recipe ?

[image: Paneer cheena melts]

Comment: When I was younger my local restaurant made paneer that would melt. Fabulous in sag/palak. I never did ask them how they did it. Wish I had.

Comment: Hehe yeah , please ask if him if you had a chance to revisit